# Parse time of day string

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

Input is a string such as "23:55" or "09:20", i.e. in the "HH:mm" format. I want the string to specify the time of day in UTC. I want to use java.time to parse the string and the output to be an Instant with the specified time of day today. If needed I can append a time zone to the string, i.e. "23:55 UTC".

I want to use the resulting instant to calculate the number of nanos between now and the mentioned instant. I.e.

```
Duration.between(Instant.now(), resultingInstant).toNanos();
```

Edit: Might have found a solution:

```
resultingInstant = LocalTime.parse("23:55").atDate(LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)).toInstant(ZoneOffset.‌​UTC)
```

Comment: Well, you better start coding then.

Comment: @Manu Is your comment due to that there is not a question mark present?

Comment: @Shirish A lot of different combos. To many to list them all here. But for example:          

`LocalTime lt2 = LocalTime.parse("17:50 UTC", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm z"));
LocalTime lt3 = LocalTime.parse("17:50 PST", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm z"));
System.out.println("Hours diff: " + Duration.between(LocalTime.now(), lt2).toHours());
System.out.println("Hours diff: " + Duration.between(LocalTime.now(), lt3).toHours());
`

Comment: @HenrikSchinzel An Instant represents a specific point in time. So how do you want to create it with only the information about hours and minutes?

Comment: @BenWin I want it to be the time today. "the output to be an Instant with the specified time of day today."

Comment: Possible solution LocalDate.now().atTime(LocalTime.parse(t1)).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)

Comment: Probably need to specify the timezone of the date: `LocalTime.parse(t1).atDate(LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use a ZonedDateTime:

```
import static java.time.ZoneOffset.UTC;
import static java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.NANOS;

LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(UTC);
ZonedDateTime resultingDate = ZonedDateTime.of(today, LocalTime.parse("23:55"), UTC);
long nanos = NANOS.between(ZonedDateTime.now(), resultingDate);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I have a surrounding system that uses Instants so I wanna stick with working with instants as not to have to do a larger rewrite.