# So I'm tring to get a date as a string at the command line and convert it into milliseconds but it keeps adding five hours. Any ideas why?

Tags: java, parsing, date, simpledateformat

This code works but when it converts the input into milliseconds it adds five hours. Is there a fix for this?

```
    ArrayList<String> timeList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter time you arrived (HH:mm:ss): ");
    timeList.add(in.next());
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"); 
    String arriveTime = timeList.get(0);
    try{
        Date date1 = format.parse(arriveTime);
        long finalTime = date1.getTime();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred");
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion). And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10725246/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29539404/642706) and many more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to guess you're in the Eastern time zone and are confusing EDT with GMT.

Comment: Wow so simple but I still missed it. Is there a way to change this?